# React. после сортировки стейт обновляется частично

Tags: reactjs

мне нужно отсортировать стейт по параметру salary.
Делаю так:

```
state = {
        workers: [
            {name: 'Bob', surname: 'Meljanski', salary: 5140},
            {name: 'Michel', surname: 'Hensson', salary: 5420},
            {name: 'Jane', surname: 'Mitchel', salary: 2054},
            {name: 'Rebeka', surname: 'Wotson', salary: 4470},
            {name: 'Max', surname: 'Payton', salary: 3920}
        ],
        typeSort: [
            'sort by ascending name',
            'sort by descending name',
            'sort by ascending surname',
            'sort by descending surname',
            'sort by ascending salary',
            'sort by descending salary'
        ],
        option: ''
    } 
 // .....
startSort = () => {
        const arr = this.state.workers.slice();

        arr[2].name = 'Mike';
        var kk = [...arr].sort((a,b) => (a.salary>b.salary)*2-1);

        this.setState(kk);
        console.log(kk);
    }
```

В результате стейт рендерится с изменённым параметром name, но без сортировки. В консоль приходит стейт изменённый по name и отсортированный по salary.

полный код тут https://codesandbox.io/s/w7o1z351pk

Answer (score 0):

значение отсортированного массива неверно записывалось в state

Правильный вариант
    this.setState({
      workers: kk
    });
Вместо 
  this.setState(kk);

Работающая версия с сортировкой по зарплате https://codesandbox.io/embed/5401noll6x